# React and Azure AD B2C IAM

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm building a React website, and I successfully integrated the Sign Up/Sign In feature into it using Azure AD B2C.

My problem is that I want to give the users permissions based on a custom attribute that needs to be added manually by an administrator on Azure Portal. I was thinking of passing the role on token claims, but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Graph API (e.g. [this](https://github.com/rbrayb/B2CGraphClient-UserManagement-MSAL)) to set the extension attribute for the user.

Then ReadByEmailAddress or whatever and then output the extension attribute as an output claim in the read and the relying party.

**Update**

In ReadByEmailAddress or whatever method you are using, add:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_abc"/>
```

This reads the extension. Add the same claim to the relying party (sign up sign in policy) to output to the JWT.

Comment: Thank you in advance for your reply, it was very useful!

I've already managed to create the extension in the user and when I run this request with the GET method (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id?$select=displayName, extension_appID_test), the extension is returned in the response.

Now I need to send the extension in the token claims to be able to use it on the website.
Can you give any more tips on how to do this?